# Reverse AutoCompleteTextView suggestions order

Tags: java, android, autocompletetextview

I am using AutoCompleteTextView to suggest items to user when typing.

Because there is no space under the textView, it shows the suggestions above the textView. That's fine and I want to keep it that way.

However, the top suggestion is still on top of the suggestion list and I would like to reverse it so it's closer to the textView.

There is an image so you can understand better what I mean.

[image: Sample]

I would like to reverse the suggestions so "Item 1" is at the bottom etc.

With implementing the AutoCompleteTextSuggestion, I followed [this tutorial](https://materialdoc.com/components/autocomplete/).

This is the code I am using right now:

```
int layoutItemId = android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line;
String[] arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items);
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,layoutItemId,arr);

AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteText);
autoCompleteView.setAdapter(adpt);
```

I keep the suggestions in string array in `res/values/strings`.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could reverse the data array itself before creating the adapter.

You can achieve that by using the [`Collections.reverse(List<T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List)) method. Something like the example below:

```
// Use the Collections.reverse() to reverse your list.
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));
Collections.reverse(myList);
// Now, create the array back again from the ArrayList.
arr = myList.toArray(new String[0]);
// Create the adapter.
ArrayAdapter<String> adpt = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,layoutItemId,arr);
```

Or... Since you're reading from a resource file to begin with... you could also write the info in reverse order.

Comment: Fantastic. I didn't realize the results are sorted just how my array is sorted. Thought the most appropriate suggestion will be always on top.
I used your code, but to create the list I had to edit it a iittle bit to look like this>
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));

Works how I wanted it to now! Thank you.

Comment: You're very welcome! And you're right, I forgot about that part. I've edited to reflect the correct solution.